# Email Client CSS/HTML Web Font Workaround

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, webfonts

Some email clients don't support web fonts, and all the proposed solutions I've seen for this are to force a backup font like Arial that's supported by the client. **My problem is that I need the default web font font to show up because it is a barcode font**.

Any workarounds to this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Given you can't get all the email clients to show your webfont  you need to rethink your statement that is in bold. No use asking for the impossible. Could you give us an example of what you need to do? In the simplest case using an image may be enough (though you can't guarantee the user is prepared to look at images). And how dynamic is this info?

Comment: @AHaworth I have an automatic email that is sent to users once they complete a form. Each user is to receive their own barcode so I thought the easiest way was to give each user a number (i.e. user #1 gets assigned 1) And display that number as a barcode. I'm just having trouble displaying that code in some clients.

Comment: Generate barcode image on your server side and attach image file with the email instead. It is not possible to do the things that email client is limited.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question.

Comment: While you can include an image with your email bear in mind that users are sometimes suspicious of images (personally I don't look at them unless I'm absolutely sure who is sending them) and also cater for those who find images difficult because of sight or cognitive disabilities. That is, make sure there is an alternative way of them getting the information in plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create an image to ensure the barcode remains the same across all email environments.

You should insert it from a hosted location that is publicly accessible, rather than using Base-64 or CID methods (not fully supported across email environments - see https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64/)

e.g.:

```
<img src="https://webserver.com/image/barcode-34234234234234.png" width="200" alt="Barcode with number 13425245452" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I wouldn't be able to use JavaScript to change the URL based on the number, since email clients don't support that either, so that code would probably have to be back end?

Comment: Yeah that's right. Depending on what system you use, essentially you'll want some variable in the URL.